# Laravel 5.3 Query Relationship data in view

Tags: laravel

I have a situation in Laravel where I have to query for relationship data in view. The problem is when I use Query builder method on the relation data of the object, all the records of the object's child relation is being returned.

I have this timezones model with attendances data being returned from the controller after being queried with filters.

```
$timezones->attendances; // Let's say I have queried and returned for all attendances in this timezone with "team_id" = 1
```

And Now in the blade view I have something like this :

```
@foreach($timezones as $timezone)
<tr>
    <th>{{ $timezone->name }}</th>
    @for($day = 1; $day <= $daysInMonth; $day++)
    <td>
            {{ count($timezone->attendances()->where([["attendance_date",\Carbon\Carbon::parse($defaultYear . '-' . $month->format('m') . '-' . $day)->format('Y-m-d')],['is_ignore',false]])->get()) }}
        </td>
    @endfor
</tr>
@endforeach
```

The above solution only returns all the attendances from the timezone object irrespective of the filters I have applied with the where query from my controller.

```
$timezones =  Timezone::with(['attendances' => function($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('team_id',$request->input('team'));
            }])->get();
```

Any help on how to achieve this in the view file?

Comment: seems you need to use scope here so it becomes method, and while you call method again it instanciates fresh query builder instance so it won't follow you previous query filter as both are different build instance.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Are you passing `$defaultYear`, `$daysInMonth` and `$month` from your controller? If so could you also paste the code for your controller in to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your initial query isn't working is because when you call the relationship as a method it will return a new instance of the query builder and not use the cached results from the original query. Also, having queries inside a loop is generally a bad idea.

The following is something that you would be able to put in your controller logic and save performing numerous unnecessary queries:

```
$timezones->map(function ($timezone) use ($defaultYear, $daysInMonth, $month) {

    $timezone->attendanceCounts = collect(range(1, $daysInMonth))
        ->flatMap(function ($day) use ($timezone, $defaultYear, $month) {

            $date = Carbon::now()->year($defaultYear)->month($month)->day($day);

            return [
                $day => $timezone->attendances
                    ->filter(function ($item) use ($date) {
                        return $item->attendance_date->isSameDay($date) && !$item->is_ignore;
                    })->count(),
            ];
        });

    return $timezone;
});
```

The above is assuming that `attendance_date` is being cast to a `Carbon` instance with `Eloquent` and that you have `$defaultYear, $daysInMonth, $month` in your controller as well. If `attendance_date` isn't a `Carbon` instance that you can change:

```
$item->attendance_date->isSameDay($date)
```

to:

```
$item->attendance_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Then in your `blade` file you can have:

```
@foreach($timezones as $timezone)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $timezone->name }}</th>
        @foreach($timezone->attendanceCounts as $count)
            <td>
                {{ $count }}
            </td>
        @endfor
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

For more information on `Collections` you can look https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections

Hope this helps!